# How come sklearn LogisticRegressionCV has worse performance than LogisticRegression?

Tags: logistic, scikit-learn

I am using Anaconda jupyter notebook to do multinomial logistic regression. The output has 3 possible results {1, 2, 3}. There are 32 independent variables. I have 50k records and I did a 80-20 split.

I am pretty new on this.

My questions are:

1. How come logistic model all give prediction of 1? basically the same as baseline model?
2. How LogisticRegressionCV with class_weight = 'balanced' has such a low accuracy? while the one without class_weight has a 'high' accuracy?

What did I do wrong?

## baseline model

```
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
dummy_model = DummyClassifier(strategy = 'most_frequent', random_state = 0)
dummy_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

result:

accuracy score: 0.9706794756329431

confusion matrix:

```
[[9700    0    0]

 [ 211    0    0]

 [  82    0    0]]
```

classification report:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.97      1.00      0.99      9700
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00       211
      3       0.00      0.00      0.00        82

avg / total       0.94      0.97      0.96      9993
```

## logit regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logit_model = LogisticRegression(C=0.05, random_state=18, class_weight='balanced', penalty='l1')
logit_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

result:
accuracy score: 0.9706794756329431

confusion matrix:

```
[[9700    0    0]

 [ 211    0    0]

 [  82    0    0]]
```

classification report:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.97      1.00      0.99      9700
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00       211
      3       0.00      0.00      0.00        82

avg / total       0.94      0.97      0.96      9993
```

## logit regression by GridSearchCV:

```
logit_model_base = LogisticRegression(random_state = 18)
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'C': [0.03, 0.05, 0.08, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 10], 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}
logit_model_best = GridSearchCV(logit_model_base, param_grid = parameters, cv = 3) 
logit_model_best.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

result:

accuracy score: 0.9706794756329431

confusion matrix:

```
[[9700    0    0]

 [ 211    0    0]

 [  82    0    0]]
```

classification report:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.97      1.00      0.99      9700
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00       211
      3       0.00      0.00      0.00        82

avg / total       0.94      0.97      0.96      9993
```

## LogisticRegressionCV with class_weight = 'balanced'

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
logit_model_cv = LogisticRegressionCV(cv = 10, class_weight = 'balanced')
logit_model_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

result:

accuracy score: 0.2982087461222856

confusion matrix:

```
[[2831 3384 3485]

 [  36  104   71]

 [   9   28   45]]
```

classification report:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.98      0.29      0.45      9700
      2       0.03      0.49      0.06       211
      3       0.01      0.55      0.02        82

avg / total       0.96      0.30      0.44      9993
```

## LogisticRegressionCV without class_weight = 'balanced'

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
logit_model_cv = LogisticRegressionCV(cv = 10)
logit_model_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

result:

accuracy score: 0.9706794756329431

confusion matrix:

```
[[9700    0    0]

 [ 211    0    0]

 [  82    0    0]]
```

classification report:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.97      1.00      0.99      9700
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00       211
      3       0.00      0.00      0.00        82

avg / total       0.94      0.97      0.96      9993
```

Comment: As this is a general statistics site, not everyone will know the functionalities provided by the sklearn functions `DummyClassifier`, `LogisticRegression`, `GridSearchCV`, and `LogisticRegressionCV`, or what the parameter settings in the function calls are intended to achieve (like the ` penalty='l1'` setting in the call to `Logistic Regression`). It would help if you could explain in words the idea behind each of the function calls. Also, have you considered using what's called a [proper scoring rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/220081/28500) for evaluating results instead?